# redefinition of an enum across multiple header files?

Tags: c++, enums

I have 4 files, A.h, B.h, C.h, C.cpp. (A.cpp and B.cpp just has the def of the functions) The problem I have is that I want to be able to build A.cpp and B.cpp independently for unit testing, but then I want C.cpp to use all the functions of both A.cpp and B.cpp together. But when I try to build for C.cpp, I keep getting redefinition error of the status enum.

I know there's a way to not define status but I am not sure what I should add so that status only gets defined once.

A.h

```
enum status
{
 allGood = 0,
 allBad  = 1
};
status somefunctionA();
```

B.h

```
enum status
{
 allGood = 0,
 allBad  = 1
};
status somefunctionB();
```

C.h

```
#include A.h
#include B.h
...
```

C.cpp

```
#include C.h
....
main()
....
somefunctionA();
somefunctionB();
```

Comment: Make one header that defines the `enum` and is included by A.h and B.h. Redefining is just asking for trouble when A.h is edited and B.h isn't.

Comment: And make sure all of the headers have proper include guards to prevent other sorts of nastiness.

Comment: Rule of thumb : one type per header file, and with an enum name like `status` I would alo use a namespace to put your enum and classes in.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way of solving this would be to create a fifth file containing the enum definition and other things used by the entire program. For example:

```
// Common.h
#pragma once 

enum status
{
 allGood = 0,
 allBad  = 1
};
```

Then in all the other files you would include this one
(`#include "Common.h"`)

Comment: This answer pretty much reiterates what @user4581301 already said in the very first comment posted here. But user4581301 was correct, and your restatement, therefore, is also correct.

Comment: No worries. I didn't write up a formal answer because I went looking for a duplicate and got busy on something else before I could find one. There's one caveat for future users of this answer: `#pragma once` may not be available on your system. The big compilers support it as best as they can (and their best is pretty good), but read the compiler docs to see if and how `once` is implemented.